# MySQL query for multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mySql table ... quite simple (id, firstColumn, secondColumn)
I want to make a query who display me the duplicate values in secondColumn with the same value in firstColumn

If i have something like that

```
1, 14, 1
2, 14, 2
3, 15, 1
4, 15, 2
5, 14, 2
6, 15, 1
7, 16, 1
8, 17, 1
```

my query to display duplicate values

```
5, 14, 2
6, 15, 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've got your desired output right? There are no duplicates in those two rows. And you're not filtering out the duplicates, otherwise you'd be showing the last two rows as well.

Comment: Why aren't `2,14,2` and `3,15,1` included in your expected results? Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column1, column2, COUNT(*)
FROM tableNAME
GROUP BY column1, column2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  t1.id,
  t1.firstColumn
FROM
  tablename t1
INNER JOIN
  tablename t2
ON
  t1.firstColumn = t2.firstColumn
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT
  id,
  firstColumn
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  id, firstcolumn
HAVING
  COUNT(*) > 1
```